# git commit message to write the following, Add 'Merge' along with userstory&defect, if merge is typed it should not ask for story number

Tags: git

Is there any regex command for writing my git commit message to write the following requirement, Add 'Merge' along with userstory and defect, if merge is typed it should not ask for story number.

I have tried with `(?i:(USERSTORY-d{6}|DEFECT-d{6}|MERGE|-d{6})):commit msg`
 but while running it my condition is not getting satisfied.

Any help on this would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the actual hook file you've written?

Comment: I have tried with (?i:(USERSTORY-d{6}|DEFECT-d{6}|MERGE|-d{6})):commit msg...this is what i have tried ...none other than that

Comment: Your hook needs to be an executable file named `.git/hooks/commit-msg`. You'll probably want it to be a shell script of some sort. Putting a pattern alone in that file won't help.

Comment: thanks for the reply but, hooks are already executable file. i'm committing a file with that message standard,  'Merge' along with userstory and defect, if merge is typed it should not ask for story number, getting error on merge is typed , it is asking story number, so i tried like this now, ^(?i:(?=MERGE)(then:\w[\w\S]{9,}$)|(elseUSERSTORY|DEFECT-\d{6}:\w[\w\S]{9,}$)), by giving if then condition, but here also getting error, please correct me if i'm wrong